# How to store ints for different screen sizes in a .xml?

Tags: android

Similar to how you can have two folders `res/values` and `res/values-xlarge`, and in each you can have a `dimens.xml` file with different dimensions...

I want to be able to store some integers (not sizes in `dp` or anything like that, just plain integers) like that. Is this possible to do in .xml? Or if not, how could I do that programmatically?

If you must know why: I am displaying a list where the user can choose to show the number of results at a time. For smaller screens, I want the default list length to be smaller than the default list length for larger screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. Just like storing a string Ressource you can store [Integers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer).

Taken from the documentation:

XML file saved at res/values/integers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="big_screen_width">12000</integer>
    <integer name="small_screen_width">320</integer>
</resources>
```

And the code would look like that

```
Resources res = getResources();
int bigScreen = res.getInteger(R.integer.big_screen_width);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was trying to do that but was writing `<int name=...` instead of `<integer name=...`. Derp.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a mechanism exactly like that. Just create an XML file in `res/values` and related folders and instead of something like:

```
<resources>
    <dimen ...>
</resource>
```

You can provide an [integer resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer):

```
<resources>
    <integer name="i">234</integer>
</resource>
```

However, in your specific scenario I'd also consider if simply changing the related layout file makes more sense.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was trying to do that but was writing `<int name=...` instead of `<integer name=...`. Derp.

Answer (score 1):

You can store things programmatically by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).